# How to send email while form submission with saving data in database

Tags: javascript, php, forms, email

Currently, our form is saving data in database on form submission but now we want (for example: to send email to email@example.com) as well. Below is the code but we are not sure, which script and where exactly we need to add.

```
              <!-- Nav tabs -->
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTabs">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Project Brief Form</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Contact Form</a></li>
              </ul>
              <!-- Tab panes -->
              <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                    <form  action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="project">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Tell us about your project in your own words? What is, for you, the main goal of the project? *</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="project" required></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Full name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full name" name="name" required>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Email / Skypename</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email / Skypename" name="email" required>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Phone</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" required>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label>How much do you want to spend?</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="spend" required>
                                  <option value="500 - 3000 $">500 - 3000 $</option>
                                  <option value="3000 - 10000 $">3000 - 10000 $</option>
                                  <option value="10000 - 50000 $">10000 - 50000 $</option>
                                  <option value="50000 - 250000 $">50000 - 250000 $</option>
                                  <option value="250000 $ +">250000 $ +</option>
                                </select>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Which services are you interested in?</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Which services are you interested in?" name="service" required>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label>How did you find out about us?</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Example: Google, Facebook, Behance..." name="about" required>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                                <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" onclick="SubmitForm('project','dubai','add_project')" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                          </div>
                          <div id="result"></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
                    <form  action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="contact">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Full name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full name" name="name" required>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Email</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Phone number</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone number" name="phone" required>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Tell us about your project in your own words? What is, for you, the main goal of the project? *</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" onclick="SubmitForm('contact','skyhigh','add_contact')" rows="4" name="about"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                            <div id="massage"></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
                  e.preventDefault()
                  $(this).tab('show');
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
              <script type="text/javascript">
function SubmitForm(FormID, Controller, FunctionName) {
           $("#"+FormID).unbind('submit').submit(function (event) {
               var formData = $( this ).serialize();
               $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST', 
                        url: "<?php echo $this->config->base_url(); ?>" + Controller + "/"+ FunctionName,
                        data: formData
                    })
                    .done(function (data) {
                        if(FormID=="project")
                        {
                        // $("#"+ ResultDivId).html(data);
                          $('<center><div class="alert alert-success success-order"><h4>Your Data Send Successfully, We will Contact You Soon.</h4></div></center>').insertBefore('#result').delay(10000).fadeOut();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          $('<center><div class="alert alert-success success-order"><h4>Your Data Send Successfully, We will Contact You Soon.</h4></div></center>').insertBefore('#massage').delay(10000).fadeOut();
                        }   
                    });

                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("#"+FormID)[0].reset();
                });
        }
</script>
```

We want to send emails while form submission as its saving data in database only.

Comment: You could use https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/ to send mails from your .php script. But be aware of spammers (to prevent spam, you could use Google reCaptcha for example)

Answer (score 0):

You should add code for email sending right where you handling a form data and saving it to database.
To send emails you'll need a properly configured server environment. It's a big topic and you haven't provided any information about your server OS. Anyway, you can just try

```
sudo apt-get install mailutils
```

on your server. I am just assuming you're running Ubuntu. Then you'll have to use Swiftmailer package and configure it to use, for example, google's smtp.
Lastly, you'll need to set-up a google account to use for sending e-mails and configure it with correct permissions to use in your app.
Like I said, it's a big topic, a lot of things must be done to achieve what you want, and your question is very general and unclear.
Alternatively, you can look at things like mailgun for simplicity.

Comment: Its a normal PHP based shared hosting.. I believe, everything is enabled as we are sending emails via thank you page on some other forms but in the above scenario, we want to send emails on the same page without redirecting to the thank you page. Above mentioned code is to save form data in database on submission, Can you please share code to add in the above code to send emails & where exactly I have to add.

Answer (score -1):

For this you will need a `mailing` system. On www.packagist.org you can find a lot of very good working composer installing projects.

For example:
https://packagist.org/packages/swiftmailer/swiftmailer

Please read the documentation on how to install and use them.

Composer can be found here incase you are not using it yet: https://getcomposer.org/

**To send an email:**

The mailing system is basically being called near the moment you save your data into the database.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18171450)

Comment: Hi Ghassen, it would be to much to include the contents of the links I added. Thats why I keep it down to only links (this time). In case the links wont work anymore, people can use google to look for something similar.